# Element by Element Comparison of Multiple Arrays in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a multiple input arrays and I want to generate one output array where the value is 0 if all elements in a column are the same and the value is 1 if all elements in a column are different.

For example, if there are three arrays :

```
A = [28, 28, 43, 43]

B = [28, 43, 43, 28]

C = [28, 28, 43, 43]

Output = [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The arrays can be of any size and any number, but the arrays are also the same size.

Comment: Are these strings or numbers?

Comment: they all can be string or number or combination of both ...

Comment: Then those are **cell** arrays, right? Those are not numeric arrays or strings.  So, if you had `A = {'28', 45};` and `B = {28, '46'};`, would the output be `[0, 1]`?  You need to update your post with more information. Your question leaves a lot to be desired when it comes to details.

Comment: Use `strcmp` for cellstrings ("arrays" of strings) and `==` for numeric arrays, chain together several tests using `&` for AND and `|`for OR.

Comment: Thanks all ... if I will convert into the equivalent number in my code ... so, now consider only numeric value and please suggest the logic for the same ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A none loopy way is to use `diff` and `any` to advantage:

```
A = [28, 28, 43,43];
B = [28, 43, 43,28];
C = [28, 28, 43,43];

D = any(diff([A;B;C])) %Combine all three (or all N) vectors into a matrix. Using the Diff to find the difference between each element from row to row. If any of them is non-zero, then return 1, else return 0.

D =  0     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several easy ways to do it.

Let's start by putting the relevant vectors in a matrix:

```
M = [A; B; C];
```

Now we can do things like:

```
idx = min(M)==max(M);
```

or

```
idx = ~var(M);
```

Answer (score 1):

No one seems to have addressed that you have a variable amount of arrays.  In your case, you have three in your example but you said you could have a variable amount.  I'd also like to take a stab at this using broadcasting.

You can create a function that will take a variable number of arrays, and the output will give you an array of an equal number of columns shared among all arrays that conform to the output you're speaking of.

First create a larger matrix that concatenates all of the arrays together, then use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to take advantage of broadcasting the first row and ensuring that you find columns that are all equal.  You can use [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to complete this step:

```
function out = array_compare(varargin)
    matrix = vertcat(varargin{:});
    out = ~all(bsxfun(@eq, matrix(1,:), matrix), 1);
end
```

This will take the first row of the stacked matrix and see if this row is the same among all of the rows in the stacked matrix for every column and returns a corresponding vector where 0 denotes each column being all equal and 1 otherwise.

Save this function in MATLAB and call it `array_compare.m`, then you can call it in MATLAB like so:

```
A = [28, 28, 43, 43];
B = [28, 43, 43, 28];
C = [28, 28, 43, 43];
Output = array_compare(A, B, C);
```

We get in MATLAB:

```
>> Output

Output =

     0     1     0     1
```

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer then unaccepted it. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Not fancy but will do the trick

```
Output=nan(length(A),1); %preallocation and check if an index isn't reached
for i=1:length(A)
    Output(i)= ~isequal(A(i),B(i),C(i));
end
```

If someone has an answer without the loop take that, but i feel like performance is not an issue here.